# MySQL Client taking more than 14 sec to be connected

Tags: mysql, database, networking, server, database-administration

IN our on-prem server we have installed mysql 4 node cluster 2 for mgmt and 2 for datanode(NDB).Max connection is 4000 and we get less than 400 concurrent connections. InnoDB Buffer pool size is 500GB.All are physical server with 1TB ram and 64 core processor. When a user trying to connect to mysql server from application VM its taking more than 14 second. But in my case while connection to that server from my computer its taking less than a second. For application VMs we provide we give them a IP range. IS ip range are the problem ? Because after connection being established its taking less than a second to fetch or get response from db server. But for each new connection its taking 14 second and this issue is while connecting from application VM. Is it a problem in networking or MySQL server ? Because while I ping db server from that server the avrg is 1.3 ms.

I have tried to increase host cache size and other variables and the connection limit is 4000 and we never got more than 400 connection. Innodb bufferpool size is 500GB.

Comment: └─$ time mysqlshow -h 10.150.150.45 -u test1 -p******* test1
Database: test1
+--------+
| Tables |
+--------+
+--------+

real    0.04s
user    0.03s
sys     0.00s
cpu     81%
Result from my computer... Database: test1
+--------+
| Tables |
+--------+
+--------+

real    0m14.952s
user    0m0.011s
sys     0m0.005s
Result from a VM

Comment: Additional DB information request from your VM application server, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.